# Are the Survival Pack: Recovery Items reusable on a different playthrough?

Tags: resident-evil-7

Is the pre-order Survival Pack a one-time use no matter the playthrough (like in Deus Ex: Mankind Divided), a one-time use per playthrough, or something different?

Comment: Given the backlash felt by Square Enix you'd hope not, but I do know it put me off bothering to pre-order because of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get your survival packs, as well as any other bonuses (preorder bonuses, unlocked items, coin from demo etc), on beginning of **each** playthrough.